# Is it possible to get the "You can perform this action again in x seconds" message removed in certain chat rooms?

Tags: discussion, support, chat

*Before you downvote because of the title, please read:*

Right now, I'm testing a Javascript chat bot in [this room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25454/ethans-playground). Now, when I need to do exstensive testing, I frequently get the message *"You can perform this actiona again in x seconds"*. This gets really annoying after a while, as *x* tends to get up to 10 seconds or higher. Is it possible to get this removed for just room?

Comment: Is this actually a [tag:feature-request]?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I do not believe that this would be allowed, because that blocker was put there to prevent it from being too much load on the server.

Imagine this: If a bunch of people got in a chat room and just started spamming it, they would be DDoS-ing the chat servers from the inside.